# Extract string between spaces

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
df <-c("AA AAAA 1B","A BBB 1", "CC RR 1W3", "SS RGTYC 0")
[1] "AA AAAA 1B" "A BBB 1" "CC RR 1W3" "SS RGTYC 0"
```

and I want to extract what is between spaces.

Desired result:

```
[1] "AAAA" "BBB" "RR" "RGTYC"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- c("AA AAAA 1B","A BBB 1", "CC RR 1W3", "SS RGTYC 0")

lst <- strsplit(df," ")
sapply(lst, '[[', 2) 
#  [1] "AAAA"  "BBB"   "RR"    "RGTYC"
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting it first and then selecting the relevant split, you can also extract it straight away using the `stringr`-package:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(df, "(?<=\\s)(.*)(?=\\s)")
# [1] "AAAA"  "BBB"   "RR"    "RGTYC"
```

This solution uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and this pattern is built up like this:

1. `(?<=\\s)` checks whether there is whitespace before
2. `(?=\\s)` checks whether there is a whitespace after
3. `(.*)` extracts everything in between the white spaces

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `gsub` based approach (from `base R`).  We match one more non-white spaces from the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more spaces or (`|`) one or more white spaces followed by non-white spaces at the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^\\S+\\s+|\\s+\\S+$", "", df)
#[1] "AAAA"  "BBB"   "RR"    "RGTYC"
```

---

There is also a convenient function `word` from `stringr`

```
stringr::word(df, 2)
#[1] "AAAA"  "BBB"   "RR"    "RGTYC"
```